# else statement within nested if statements. How does this code know which else statement to execute?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested-if

I get the nested if loops (same as using && operator), but how does this code here know which conditions to execute with no conditions and just back to back else statements?  One of them is within the nested if statements.  I can tell that's obviously why this works the way it does, I just don't get how.  Also, I know how to write this in several more readable ways testing multiple conditions.  Please just explain what is happening with this code here.  How does it know to output "You are too old" or "You are too young?"

```
var age = prompt("Please enter Your age here :");
var min_age=18;
var max_age=40;

if(age>=min_age){
 if(age<=max_age){
   console.log("You meet the requirements for this competition");
 }else{
  console.log("You are too old");
 }
}else{
 console.log("You are too young");
}
```

Comment: *How does this code know which else statement to execute?* The curly braces.

Comment: If age is greater or equal than min_age > (if age is less or equal than max_age > You meet the requirements ; else > You are too old) else > You are too young. Just read the code.

Comment: Put in other words: The wrapping `if else` is executed first. If the age is _under_ 18, it will just execute the `else` and say you're too young. Otherwise, it will go on the the next `if else`, and forget about the previous one. If the age is _under_ 40, it will say that you meet the requirements, and do nothing more. Otherwise, it will execute the `else` bound to the current `if`, and say you're too old. But really, you should allow everyone to participate. No discrimination.

Comment: @blex Ahhh, thank you.  I knew it was something dumb tripping me up. Just never seen it written like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-then-else ambiguity is known for a long time. All languages have solved it by defining that an `else` will match the first perceding `if`. So:

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        x = 1;
else
    x = 2;
```

resolves to:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        x = 1;
    }
    else {
        x = 2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** by Nisar's reuest:

The `if` statement is defined as:

```
if (<condition>) <statement> [else <statement>]
```

This means that a `<statement>` in the above may also be an `if` statement. So, for example:

```
if (<condition>) if (<condition>) [else <statement>] [else <statement>]
```

As each `else` part is optional, the compiler has no way of knowing when it sees an `else` part to which `if` it belongs. To solve that the language *defines* that an `else` always matches the first preceding `if`.

Comment: Clear answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @nisar: see addition to the answer. Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's **indent** your code.

```
var age = prompt("Please enter Your age here :");
var min_age = 18;
var max_age = 40;

if (age >= min_age)
{
    if (age <= max_age)
    {
        console.log("You meet the requirements for this competition");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("You are too old");
    }
}
else
{
    console.log("You are too young");
}
```

**Starting off..**

```
var age = prompt("Please enter Your age here :");
```

Let's say you enter *21* in the prompt box, so `age=21`

We initialize

```
var min_age = 18;
var max_age = 40;
```

Now let's look at the first `if` condition.

```
 if (age >= min_age)
```

If you substitute the values,this translates to

```
if (21 >= 18)
```

**This is true,therefore we go inside the if block and not to the else.**
The next line is.

```
 if (age <= max_age)
```

This translates to

```
 if (21 <= 40)
```

Considering this is also true, we print *You meet the requirements for this competition*.

*The most important take-away from this is, indent your code, and the rest becomes pretty simple.*

Comment: Yeah, it was copy pasted off of another tutorial.  I wouldn't write anything like this lol.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets `{}` set the limit.

Try to think in pseudocode, look beyond the characters and think about what is happening.

Reading in order:

```
If you are old enough
  If your are not too old 
    'You meet the requirements for this competition'
  OTHERWISE
    'You are too old'
  END
OTHERWISE
  'You are too young'
END
```

Note how indentation can help see the limits of the conditions. Each indented part can be separated.

Comment: Yeah, had just never seen it written like this before, was throwing me off.  Should have done the pseudo approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are just 3 Options

- too young
- correct age
- too old

First Check - is the person old enough?

```
if(age>=min_age)
```

Second check - is the person too old?

```
if(age<=max_age)
```

the only possible option left after this if statment is `FALSE` :

- too old